# Need help parsing a twitter xml document into variables in VB.NET?

Tags: xml, vb.net, parsing, twitter

Ok so I have spent a day or so trying to get this working.  I need to parse an xml document from twitter selecting certain nodes and placing the value in variables.  I get an error...Conversion from string "user/screen_name" to type 'Integer' is not valid.  Parsing XML is out of my league.  any help would be appreciated... here is what i have so far.

First the Twitter XML file...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<statuses type="array">
<status>
<created_at>Sat Apr 30 04:10:46 +0000 2011</created_at>
<id>64179865481510912</id>
<text>@sixrevisions implementing the Twitter API for my new portfolio site!</text>
<source><a href="http://twitter.com/#!/download/iphone" rel="nofollow">Twitter for iPhone</a></source>
<truncated>false</truncated>
<favorited>false</favorited>
<in_reply_to_status_id>64087873804189696</in_reply_to_status_id>
<in_reply_to_user_id>14444403</in_reply_to_user_id>
<in_reply_to_screen_name>sixrevisions</in_reply_to_screen_name>
<retweet_count>0</retweet_count>
<retweeted>false</retweeted>
<user>
  <id>92868468</id>
  <name>Timothy Antonucci</name>
  <screen_name>TimAtWerked</screen_name>
  <location>Boston, MA</location>
  <description>My name is Tim a web designer/developer in Boston, I love cars and photography ;-)</description>
  <profile_image_url>http://a2.twimg.com/profile_images/1336500668/wrkdtwitico_normal.gif</profile_image_url>
  <url>http://www.werked.com</url>
  <protected>false</protected>
  <followers_count>14</followers_count>
  <profile_background_color>b2c789</profile_background_color>
  <profile_text_color>333333</profile_text_color>
  <profile_link_color>0084B4</profile_link_color>
  <profile_sidebar_fill_color>b3d6af</profile_sidebar_fill_color>
  <profile_sidebar_border_color>6e996a</profile_sidebar_border_color>
  <friends_count>34</friends_count>
  <created_at>Fri Nov 27 00:35:31 +0000 2009</created_at>
  <favourites_count>0</favourites_count>
  <utc_offset>-18000</utc_offset>
  <time_zone>Eastern Time (US & Canada)</time_zone>
        <profile_background_image_url>http://a3.twimg.com/profile_background_images/97017170/1440x900sm.jpg</profile_background_image_url>
  <profile_background_tile>true</profile_background_tile>
  <profile_use_background_image>true</profile_use_background_image>
  <notifications />
  <geo_enabled>false</geo_enabled>
  <verified>false</verified>
  <following />
  <statuses_count>39</statuses_count>
  <lang>en</lang>
  <contributors_enabled>false</contributors_enabled>
  <follow_request_sent />
  <listed_count>0</listed_count>
  <show_all_inline_media>false</show_all_inline_media>
  <default_profile>false</default_profile>
  <default_profile_image>false</default_profile_image>
  <is_translator>false</is_translator>
</user>
<geo />
<coordinates />
<place />
<contributors />
</status>
</statuses>
```

Next my code...

```
 Dim m_xmld As XmlDocument
 Dim m_nodelist As XmlNodeList
 Dim m_node As XmlNode
 m_xmld = New XmlDocument()
 m_xmld.Load("http://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/user_timeline.xml?screen_name=timatwerked&count=4&include_rts=true")
 m_nodelist = m_xmld.SelectNodes("/statuses/status")
 For Each m_node In m_nodelist
    Dim twitName = m_node.ChildNodes.Item("screen_name").InnerText
    Dim twitrName = m_node.ChildNodes.Item("name").InnerText
    Dim twitText = m_node.ChildNodes.Item("text").InnerText
    Dim twitPic = m_node.ChildNodes.Item("profile_image_url").InnerText
    Dim twitTime = m_node.ChildNodes.Item("created_at").InnerText
    twitPic = twitPic.Replace("normal", "mini")
    twitProLink = "http://www.twitter.com/" & twitName
    'Do Stuff with variables
 Next
```

---

Ok So I should have paid more attention to the error and Visual Studio.  Item retrieves a node at the given index as an integer.  I was searching for the string name so I just counted the Items from 0 and used the number that item was looking for... see the code below.

```
 Dim m_xmld As XmlDocument
 Dim m_nodelist As XmlNodeList
 Dim m_node As XmlNode
 m_xmld = New XmlDocument()
 m_xmld.Load("http://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/user_timeline.xml?screen_name=timatwerked&count=4&include_rts=true")
 m_nodelist = m_xmld.SelectNodes("/statuses/status")
 For Each m_node In m_nodelist
   Dim twitName = m_node.ChildNodes.Item(11).ChildNodes.Item(2).InnerText
   Dim twitrName = m_node.ChildNodes.Item(11).ChildNodes.Item(1).InnerText
   Dim twitText = m_node.ChildNodes.Item(2).InnerText
   Dim twitPic = m_node.ChildNodes.Item(11).ChildNodes.Item(5).InnerText
   Dim twitTime = m_node.ChildNodes.Item(0).InnerText
   twitPic = twitPic.Replace("normal", "mini")
   twitProLink = "http://www.twitter.com/" & twitName
   'Do stuff with variables
  Next
```

Now the only problem which will be a simple fix is a retweet doesn't display correctly because the nodes are different so I'll just add a If then to see if it is a retweet then adjust the nodes accordingly.  Thanks again.

Comment: Ok no problem figured I answered my own question since it works now just posted the solution I found as an answer so others could see how I fixed it, it's not more details or another question it was the answer that fixed my problem

Comment: Now, if you want to post an answer to your question, that's different.  Feel free to add that.  But if you need to update your question with more details, do please edit in future.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The solution you illustrated is not a good solution, because your code will break if the order of the nodes ever changes.  The technique you have illustrated is referred to as "magic numbers".  A better way to to use XPath to parse the xml object.  That way, the order of the nodes is irrelevant.

Answer (score 0):

I think you would need

```
Dim twitName = m_node.ChildNodes.Item("user").ChildNodes.Item("screen_name").InnerText
```

and similar stuff for retrieving other elements.

Comment: Thank You very much Bala, it still hasn't worked using this method... but it did bring me a step closer... much need information. Thanks again. I will post the answer with the code I used.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

`For Each m_node In m_nodelist
   Dim twitName = m_node.ChildNodes.Item("user").ChildNodes.Item("screen_name").Value
   'OtherNodes
   'Do stuff with variables
Next`

InnerText assumes that the item you set or get has children. Value only grabs the Value of the Item with no children assumed, and as BalaR Stated refer to the item by name, so if the twitter API ever updates your index pointer will be recalculated.